# How to get the key and the value from a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, key

I'm messing around with the dictionary in wpf. I'm storing data from a database in the  dictionary - as a question and an answer.

```
string question = "color of sun";
string answer ="yellow";

Dictionary<string,string> questions = new Dictionary<string,string>();

questions.Add(question, answer);
```

How do I get the get the questions stored in the Dictionary back?
The "color of sun" and "yellow" is only an example.

I'm trying to get the key and value out of the dictionary like this:
string a = question.keys;
string b = questions.values;

I have tried in several other ways, and looked around on the internet, but with little luck.

```
Dictionary<string, string> questions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Comment: Dictionary\<\string, string\>\ dic = new Dictionary\<\string, string\>\();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the the value in the Dic:

```
string q = questions["Key"];
```

and you can get the key collection:

```
 List<string> keys = questions.Keys.ToList<string>();
 List<string> values = questions.Values.ToList<string>();
```

i hope this help you! if not please explain more what you need.

Comment: Tnx a lot, this helped :)